# Why are trichomes important for both the roots and shoots of plants?

Tags: plant-anatomy

In what ways are trichomes vital to the plant?

Why have them on the plant shoots as well?

Comment: This question would be better with more context. Trichome is a generic term for diverse, often microscopic, structures with a wide variety of functions. The question "but how does that work" should be addressed separately.

Comment: Ok let me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plant leaf hairs, or trichomes are vital for many reasons.

Interestingly in 1975 researchers were correct when they stated:

> *"It can be argued that essentially the same genetic system should be required for both root hairs and trichomes."* [[1]](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02860838)(Pay-wall)

For example:

- *C. salvifolius*, there are more adaxial trichomes present to avoid UV light from injuring the abaxial surface.[[2]](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17143807/)(Pay-wall)
- Increased transpiration [[3]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrm1404?proof=t)(Pay-wall)
- Protecting against insect herbivores [[4]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrm1404?proof=t)(Pay-wall)
- Increasing tolerance to freezing [[5]](https://www.nature.com/articles/nrm1404?proof=t)(Pay-wall)